# h1 Tag hover effect doesn't work in list

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li h1  {
    font-size: 40.5px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
/* PADDING FOR NAV */
.navp {
    padding-right: 45px;
}
#reflect h1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}


#reflect {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -30px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}

#reflect:before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 277px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  width: 360px;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtRot"><h1>HOME<h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtOrange"><h1>ANGEBOT<h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGelb"><h1>TEAM<h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGruen"><h1>UMWELT<h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="txtBlau"><h1>KONTAKT<h1></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My goal is to put an underline on the H1 tag when i hover over it. What's my mistake?
I've tried also:

```
h1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

But this also doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try closing your H1 tags with a `</h1>`, that seems to sort the issue for me: https://jsfiddle.net/rg4hqw21/...

Comment: Agree with @DavidWilkinson. and `!important` is useless here. Take care by using this method

Comment: This didn't help.. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @olivier then there's likely another style elsewhere in your CSS that's overriding it..

Comment: @olivier id must be unique in your DOM. Use reflect as class instead of id

Comment: Thanks @Alexis i found it. Now i can use the normal LI

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your h1 tags incorrectly. To close you need to add the `/` so that the tag is as follows:

```
<h1>content</h1>
```

Also, you shouldn't be using h1 tags for things that aren't headers. Try using something like spans.

This gives you the following:

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li span  {
    font-size: 40.5px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
/* PADDING FOR NAV */
.navp {
    padding-right: 45px;
}
.reflect span:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.reflect {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -30px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}

.reflect:before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 277px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="reflect navp txtRot"><span>HOME</span></li>
        <li class="reflect navp txtOrange"><span>ANGEBOT</span></li>
        <li class="reflect navp txtGelb"><span>TEAM</span></li>
        <li class="reflect navp txtGruen"><span>UMWELT</span></li>
        <li class="reflect txtBlau"><span>KONTAKT</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You should also use `reflect` as a class instead of an id, as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
     <li id="reflect" class="navp txtRot"><h1>HOME<h1></li>
     <li id="reflect" class="navp txtOrange"><h1>ANGEBOT<h1></li>
     <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGelb"><h1>TEAM<h1></li>
     <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGruen"><h1>UMWELT<h1></li>
     <li id="reflect" class="txtBlau"><h1>KONTAKT<h1></li>
</ul>
```

You don't seem to have closed your h1 tags. `<h1>HOME<h1>`

You need to close them off. Just like you did with your unordered list tags `<ul></ul>` you  must close off each header tag as well `<h1>HOME</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close `<h1>` by `</h1>`

Besides however having multiple h1 is allowed, but remember that the goal of heading tags is to help search engines to better understand the primary subject matter of each page.

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
nav ul li  {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li h1  {
    font-size: 40.5px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
/* PADDING FOR NAV */
.navp {
    padding-right: 45px;
}
#reflect h1:hover {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}


#reflect {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -30px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}

#reflect:before {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box, -moz-element(#reflect) no-repeat scroll 0 -127px content-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  height: 140px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 277px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtRot"><h1>HOME</h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtOrange"><h1>ANGEBOT</h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGelb"><h1>TEAM</h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="navp txtGruen"><h1>UMWELT</h1></li>
        <li id="reflect" class="txtBlau"><h1>KONTAKT</h1></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```